# objective c,checking file exist at path

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a screen using Objective-C in an iPhone project. In that, there are 2 buttons (say A and B). On the click of button A, one xml file will be created in a folder (say INBOX).

My problem is, I need to create the file only if it does not exist at folder INBOX.
How can I do this? Can any one tell me the syntax?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Can you Please Check NSFileManager.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *pathForFile;

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathForFile]){ 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
- (BOOL)checkAndCopy {
    NSError **error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFile.xml"]; 

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        // this copy an existing xml (empty?) file from main bundle:
        // try else to create a new file

        NSString *bundle =  [[ NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourFile" ofType:@"xml"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:error];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There have been similar questions on SO before:

1. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354007/error-while-checking-if-a-file-exists/1354049#1354049) answer is probably most appropriate for you

Link to the [NSFileManagerAPI](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/)