# Saved image does not appear in file directory

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

I'm using the following code below save an image locally. It works without any errors, and I can preview the incoming image. The only problem is that the image never seems to actually be saved or appear in the Images directory. I use iExplorer to double check, and I have refreshed the folder and the image is still not there. Your thoughts are appreciated.

```
// I can preview this UIImage and it appears as expected
UIImage *image    = [UIImage imageWithData:responseObject]; //responseImage is an image from online 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docs = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path =  [docs stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Images/image1.jpg"];

NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .8)];
NSError *writeError = nil;

if(![imageData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError]) {
    //This never fires, so you would think the image would have saved, but that does not appear to be the case!
    NSLog(@"%@: Error saving image: %@", [self class], [writeError localizedDescription]);
}
```

I did also [check to see if the file exists programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075416/objective-c-checking-file-exist-at-path) and apparently it **does** exist. However, when I try to reference it within a UIWebview, it doesn't load anything for that image.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `NSFileManagers` use `NSString` paths to read/write files, however `UIWebViews` use `NSURLs`. In order for you to load the file into a `UIWebView`, you'll need to convert your `NSString` path into an `NSURL` file URL.

So instead of something that looks like:

```
/Documents/Path/To/File.png
```

It needs to be

```
file:///Documents/Path/To/File.png
```

I believe the correct way to do this is to use the [`[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:) method.

---

So it would look something like this:

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString* path; //However you got your path here

if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: fileURL];
    [_myWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers. I did already take this into account, and now it does seem to be loading in the `UIWebview` after I changed my error checking code in your previous answer. As well, after reloading iExplorer completely, the images do show up. I have no idea why it wasn't working in the beginning, but your better error checking code was certainly very useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long to post as a comment, so I'm posting it as an answer.

---

I'm not sure about your if statement there. It does return a BOOL NO if the file operation fails, but I'm not exactly sure what *"the operation fails"* means. Just because the file is not written out does not necessarily mean that the operation failed. So it's better to check the `NSError` itself.

Instead of checking `![writeToFile]`, run the line without the if statement, and then check `if(writeError != nil)`. If the if statement is true, then something went wrong, and if so, you can check the localized description of the error.

So to recap,

```
NSError* writeError = nil;
[imageData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError];
if(writeError != nil)
{
    //Something went wrong
    NSLog("File write error: %@", writeError.localizedDescription);
}
```