# file exist but cannot open?

Tags: iphone, ios

Save Mechanics I have used:

```
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:self forKey:@"Save"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    [archiver release];
    [data release];
```

I have used

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savePath];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[SynchronizedData createPath] error:&error]
```

to check the existences of my file. They confirm the file exist.

However I cannot load the file with the same directory path

```
    //NSData *encodedData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:[SynchronizedData createPath]];

    NSData *encodedData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:tempFilePath] autorelease];

    if (encodedData == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Save cannot open while loading!");
        return nil;
    }
```

The above encodedData, both returned nil. (autorelease is not the problem, i've checked)

Any ideas what's wrong?

I found similar case in [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354007/error-while-checking-if-a-file-exists/1354049#1354049), I tried retain once more my tempFilePath, it doesn't matter, the problem still exist.

---

I have done the save in a more simpler mechanism than the above one.

The problem remained unsolved for getting the NSData from directory. Maybe due to Read Permission mentioned by @paxdiablo.

Thus I use "Documents" folder instead of "Library". The NSData open has no error.

Comment: What is `tempFilePath` ?

Comment: tempFilePath is just the same path with savePath/[SynchronizedData createPath]

Comment: Please NSLog the tempFilePath and check is it correct or not.

Comment: because I dont fully understand the file I/O methods, so I tried putting the save directory (/var/mobile/Applications/AA414ECF-337D-485A-A5D7-09159D042C64/Library/PlayerProfile/gameData.dat) as well as the folder directory (/var/mobile/Applications/AA414ECF-337D-485A-A5D7-09159D042C64/Library/PlayerProfile) into tempFilePath to test my function. Both of them failed ofcoz

Comment: The save directory is correct, check that is anything in the gameData.dat file. I think it is empty

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the question is, how can I check the file is empty in another way from opening a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file can exist but still not be readable. You should probably start by checking the permissions on that file.

Also, use the [`initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) variant to get an error back - that should hopefully tell you if there's a problem.

And, based on your comment that you're seeing:

> Cocoa error 257

it appears the permissions are the problem. If you look at the [Foundation constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html), you'll see:

> NSFileReadNoPermissionError = 257

meaning that you have no permission to read that file.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I have check the NSData class reference. I think you are talking about 'initWithContentsOfFile: options: error:' right? I have got the error :The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 257.)

Comment: @user1824022, then it's a permissions problem as I thought. From the Foundation constants, 257 is a read-permission failure - see my update.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have post the save mechanics I have used. It is basically [NSData writeToFile]. However, I found no articles mentioning the read permission...